# UIDocumentInteractionController delegate method do not called when pressed on mail button

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to show the Alert message When no mail is configured on the device.But when i click Mail from document interaction it just simply dismiss the controller none of the two following Delegate method will call.Please refer Image for better understanding.

Please help. Thanks in Advance

```
- (void)openAppList:(FileInfo *)fileinfo {

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileinfo.fullName];

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];

    [interactionController retain];

    interactionController.delegate = self;
    BOOL present = [interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.tabBarController.view animated:YES];
    if (!present) {
    [MainteOrErrorDialog initWithErrorCode:kAlertNotOpenInFileId filename:fileInfo.filename target:nil action:nil];
    } else {
    [interactionController retain];
    }
```

}

```
#pragma UIDocumentInteractionDelegate
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
        willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{

}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller 
           didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't really interact with the Mail delegates through UIDocumentInteractionController. UIDocumentInteractionController is extremely limited to what you can do with properties and attributes of all apps it supports, you can't even set a mails message body to a custom message. In fact, `documentInteractionController:canPerformAction:` is deprecated in iOS 6.0 because Apple was moving towards UIActivityViewController. [They're own deprecated statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate/documentInteractionController:canPerformAction:) is :

> Apps should use UIActivityViewController for actions

---

So alternatively, with UIActivityViewController you can.

A work around for this, implement UIActivityViewController, they both support the same apps and check if a user can send emails, if not, exclude Mail from the menu :

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
      NSArray *shareItems;
      shareItems = @[[Config emailMessage], snapshot]; //emailMessage is an NSString containing the body of the mail or mms message located in a different VC
      UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
      [activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:(UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)^(NSString *string, BOOL completed) {
      }
      [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
 } else {
      NSArray *shareItems;
      shareItems = @[[Config emailMessage], snapshot]; //emailMessage is an NSString containing the body of the mail or mms message located in a different VC
      UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
      activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMail];
      [activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:(UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler)^(NSString *string, BOOL completed) {
      }
      [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```