# UIDocumentInteractionController shows unwanted behaviour with options

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting the following error just after I press one of the document interaction controller buttons i.e. mail etc:

```
LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called
```

My email is not configured with iPhone Device.I want to show the alert for that.

Here is the code that creates the interaction controller - the URL etc is all valid however the delegate calls don't hit my controller even though I have implemented the delegate methods.

```
- (void)openAppList:(FileInfo *)fileinfo {

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileinfo.fullName];

UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
[interactionController retain];

interactionController.delegate = self;
BOOL present = [interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero                                       inView:self.tabBarController.view
                                                        animated:YES];
if (!present) {
    [MainteOrErrorDialog initWithErrorCode:kAlertNotOpenInFileId filename:fileInfo.filename target:nil action:nil];
} else {
    [interactionController retain];
}
```

}

UIDocumentInteractionDelegate Method

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
    willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{
     NSLog(@"Will Begin: %@", application);   
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller 
       didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Did End: %@", application);    
}
```

Comment: Why are you retaining? but its nothing short of a bug. worry not. also a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183334/uiactivityviewcontroller-launchservices-invalidationhandler-called

Comment: If i won't retain then it show the Unhandled exception and LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called

Comment: its just a bug, and it doesn't effect user performance or do anything really but display in the console log

Comment: Can you Please explain me how it is duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183334/uiactivityviewcontroller-launchservices-invalidationhandler-called ,it only show same error,But it is not same thing.

Comment: it's part of the [Launch Services Keys Network](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) doesn't matter if it's UIActivityViewController or not, it's purpose is the same.

Comment: you can check if a user has email set up like this : `if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,But i am not using the MFMailCompose it automatically came into document interaction. Just tell me how can i call the delegate method when i press mail button from document interaction

Comment: you said "My email is not configured with iPhone Device.I want to show the alert for that" i assumed that meant you want to show an alert if email isn't set up. I know that it automatically comes up, the apps automatically generate based off the document type your sharing. if your asking about the MFMailCompose delegate method is : `- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error`

Comment: Please refer the link for better understanding of my bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085606/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-delegate-method-do-not-called-when-pressed-on-ma